# Create and dynamically allocate multiple versions of a class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

Due to different hardware versions of a project I am working on, there are two versions of a c++ class which control the hardware. The version of the class that should be used should be determined during runtime and therefore the instantiation needs to occur dynamically. The function names and return types of the two class are always the same.

How should I go about creating such a class? I have read up on polymorphism and class inheritance, and tried writing the following code, but it does not work. I feel that I am going in the right direction but lack the experience to solve this problem fully. My implementation below does not create the classes dynamically, which I think is what causes my issue.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class HWVer1                     { 
    private: 
        std::string _msg; 
    public:
        HWVer1(std::string x): _msg(x) {} 
        void do_something(){ std::cout<<"hello from HWVer1: "<<_msg <<"\n"; } 
}; 

class HWVer2                     { 
    private: 
        std::string _msg; 
    public:
        HWVer2(std::string x): _msg(x) {} 
        void do_something(){ std::cout<<"hello from HWVer2: "<<_msg <<"\n"; } 
}; 

class Wrapper1: public         HWVer1 { public: Wrapper1(std::string x):HWVer1(x){}  }; 
class Wrapper2: public         HWVer2 { public: Wrapper2(std::string x):HWVer2(x){}  }; 



int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    
    int HW_ver = 2;
    
    if (HW_ver == 1){
        Wrapper1 HW("Wrap1");
    }
    
    else if (HW_ver == 2){
        Wrapper2 HW("Wrap2"); 
    }

    HW.do_something();  //  error: ‘HW’ was not declared in this scope --> does not work because reference to HW is destroyed after scope of if /else if statement ends 

}
```

Note: the reason why HW.do_something() isn't inside of the if statements is because the functions found in HWVer1/HWVer2 are used in many many places throughout the code. And the whole point of this exercise is to avoid an if/else if statement before every access to the hardware class. I just want to change a little bit of overhead and leave the rest of the code as it is. For this to work the declared HW class needs to be globally accessible, as this is how the individual versions of the hardware class are currently implemented.

Update:

I have solved my issue. The following seems to work:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


class HWVerBase
{ 
    public:
        virtual void do_something() = 0;
        virtual void do_something_else() = 0;
}; 

class HWVer1: public HWVerBase
{
    public:
        void do_something(void){
            std::cout << "I am in HWVer1!" << std::endl;
        }
        void do_something_else(void){
            std::cout << "I am doing something else in HWVer1!" << std::endl;
        }
};

class HWVer2: public HWVerBase
{
    public:
        void do_something(void){
            std::cout << "I am in HWVer2!" << std::endl;
        }
        void do_something_else(void){
            std::cout << "I am doing something else in HWVer2!" << std::endl;
        }
};


int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    
    int HW_ver = 1;
    
    HWVerBase* ptrHWVer;
    
    if (HW_ver == 1){
        ptrHWVer = new HWVer1;
    }
    
    else if (HW_ver == 2){
        ptrHWVer = new HWVer2;
    }    
    
    ptrHWVer->do_something();
    ptrHWVer->do_something_else();

    delete ptrHWVer;    

}
```

Outputs:

I am in HWVer1!
I am doing something else in HWVer1!

The only "downside" of this approach is that all functions defined as virtual must also be defined in both HWVer1 and HWVer2 classes. I think this might be possible to be avoided if were able to use the std::shared_ptr as MSalters suggests below. But unfortunately the system I am compiling on does not have access to this version of C++. So this (fairly basic) method will do for now. Thanks to everyone who contributed.

Comment: move `HW.do_something();` inside `if`?

Comment: You can't have a single object that can directly store either a `Wrapper1` or a `Wrapper2` because there is no relationship between `Wrapper1` and `Wrapper2`. If they had a common base type, you could use polymorphism. You could still achieve this with extra steps, like by using `std::variant`.

Comment: @appleapple I updated my question with an edit at the end to explain why I want to avoid this

Comment: Have you considered just using a type alias like `using my_type = Wrapper1;` instead? Do you need to propagate different types based on runtime information? The example shown doesn't, but that could just be due to oversimplifying the example.

Comment: look at curiously reccuring template pattern (crtp)

Comment: "My implementation below does not create the classes dynamically" What is stopping you from doing so? Do you understand how to use things like `new` and `delete` or `std::unique_ptr`? (And by the way you'll probably end up wanting to make do_something `virtual`.)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Do you need to propagate different types based on runtime information? --> Yes and your hunch is correct, the example I gave is just to simplify what I am trying to do.

Comment: @TheUndeadFish I am not really sure to be honest. I know how to use new and delete but only in a limited sense. Yes, virtual is needed if I want the children to override the function name declared in the wrapper class, right?

Comment: "The only "downside" of this approach is that all functions defined as virtual must also be defined in both HWVer1 and HWVer2 classes". This is not true. When you want to force derived class to implement a function you mark it with

virtual void do_something() = 0;

This is called "pure virtual"
If you want to make it optional to override you can make it just "virtual"

virtual void do_something_else() {
 // your default impl here
};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a base class:

```
class HWVerBase                     { 
    private: 
        std::string _msg; 
    public:
        HWVerBase(std::string x): _msg(x) {} 
        virtual void do_something() = 0;
};
```

The `virtual void do_something() = 0;` means that both HWVer1 and HWVer2 must implement this method.

You can now create a `std::shared_ptr<HWVerBase>` which can hold either `std::make_shared<HWVer1>` or `std::make_shared<HWVer2>`. Since this is a pointer, you need `->` as in `HW->do_something()`

Comment: Sorry, I am not so well-versed in shared_ptr or make_shared. Would you mind elaborating that last point a bit more?

Comment: Also the complier I am using basic C++ and will not have access to the shared_ptr I believe.

Comment: @cwm5412: `shared_ptr` has been in C++ for a decade. It should be both in your textbook and in your compiler.

Comment: OK yes maybe it works, I will try it out. But just to be clear, this means that HWVer1 and HWVer2 should be children of the base class HWVerBase, yes?

Comment: @cwm5412: Yes: `class HWVer1 : public HWVerBase { ...`

Comment: So I got it working using your suggestion but I essentially reached the same result as my previous attempt: it is not possible to work: it doesn't seem like I am able to create an object linking to the correct HWVer1 or HWVer2 dynamically. Any further tips? Thanks for the help so far btw.

Comment: bad news, I got it working on an online complier using my example code but it seems like the compiler on our linux systems, where the code has to compile, does not have c+11 so share_ptr is indeed not available.

Comment: @cwm5412: If not homework, check out Boost. `std::shared_ptr` is directly derived from `boost::shared_ptr`.

Comment: Hey MSalters, thanks for the help. Boost also doesn't seem to be available on the system I am working with. So I redid the approach using "plain-old" pointers and it worked, see my edits above. Your answer was the most helpful to point me in the right direction so I will accept it as the solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where something needs to outlive the scope (the braces) where it's created. That's essentially what dynamic allocation is intended for.

So what you seem to be looking for is something like:

```
class Base {
    // Stuff....
}

class Derived : public Base {
    // Other stuff....
}



Base* ptr = nullptr;   // or NULL if you don't have nullptr

if (HW_ver == 1) {
    ptr = new Base();
}
else if (HW_ver == 2) {
    ptr = new Derived();
}

ptr->do_something();

delete ptr;
```

Of course if you are able to use `std::unique_ptr` (or even `std::auto_ptr` from past C++ standards, which is at least OK for this usage), then you can replace the raw `Base* ptr` so that you don't have to remember to ensure `delete ptr` is called.

Also note that `do_something` needs to be declared as `virtual` in `Base`. (Otherwise `ptr->do_something` would always call the Base version even when a Derived object is involved.)

A good C++ book or such educational materials would serve you well for this stuff. It's pretty fundamental to understand. Questions-and-answers on internet forums are unlikely to cover all the things you ought to know.

Answer (score -1):

You need to call the method while the object is still alive:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    
    int HW_ver = 2;
    
    if (HW_ver == 1){
        Wrapper1 HW("Wrap1");
        HW.do_something();
    }
    
    else if (HW_ver == 2){
        Wrapper2 HW("Wrap2"); 
        HW.do_something();
    }
}
```

If you need to call more than one method, you can either make the two inherit from a common base or place all the common code in a function template. Something along the line of:

```
 template <typename T> 
 void foo(T& t) {
     t.do_something();
     t.do_something_else();
     ... more ...
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you do not like to use new, delete, or inheritance you can try a Solution with std::variant:
[Wandbox Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/eRrA6U0CokKCZecF)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>

// helper type for the visitor #4
template <class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts...
{
  using Ts::operator()...;
};
// explicit deduction guide (not needed as of C++20)
template <class... Ts> overloaded (Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;

class HWVer1
{
private:
  std::string _msg;

public:
  HWVer1 (std::string x) : _msg (x) {}
  void
  do_something () const
  {
    std::cout << "hello from HWVer1: " << _msg << "\n";
  }
};

class HWVer2
{
private:
  std::string _msg;

public:
  HWVer2 (std::string x) : _msg (x) {}
  void
  do_something () const
  {
    std::cout << "hello from HWVer2: " << _msg << "\n";
  }
};

typedef std::variant<std::monostate, HWVer1, HWVer2> Hardware;

// clang-format off
const auto handleMyHardware=overloaded{ 
                          [] (auto hw) {
                            hw.do_something ();
                          },
                          [] (std::monostate) {
                            std::cout << "not set" << std::endl;
                          } };
// clang-format on
int
main ()
{
  auto useHardware1 = true;
  auto hardware = Hardware{};
  if (useHardware1)
    {
      hardware = HWVer1{ "huhu" };
    }
  else
    {
      hardware = HWVer2{ "huhu" };
    }
  std::visit (handleMyHardware, hardware);
}
```

Output:
Start

hello from HWVer1: huhu

0

Finish

Personally I would try to use simple structs to get some locality. So I can see what happens in the handleMyHardware lambda expression.
[Wandbox Demo 2](https://wandbox.org/permlink/R4hSGEjH5XAtNtY4)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>

// helper type for the visitor #4
template <class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts...
{
  using Ts::operator()...;
};
// explicit deduction guide (not needed as of C++20)
template <class... Ts> overloaded (Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;

struct HWVer1
{
  std::string _msg;
};

struct HWVer2
{
  std::string _msg;
};

typedef std::variant<std::monostate, HWVer1, HWVer2> Hardware;

// clang-format off
const auto handleMyHardware=overloaded{ 
                          [] (HWVer1 const& hw) {
                            std::cout << "hello from HWVer1: " << hw._msg << "\n";
                          },
                          [] (HWVer2 const& hw) {
                            std::cout << "hello from HWVer2: " << hw._msg << "\n";
                          },
                          [] (std::monostate) {
                            std::cout << "hardware not set" << "\n";
                          } };
// clang-format on
int
main ()
{
  auto useHardware1 = true;
  auto hardware = Hardware{};
  if (useHardware1)
    {
      hardware = HWVer1{ "huhu" };
    }
  else
    {
      hardware = HWVer2{ "huhu" };
    }
  std::visit (handleMyHardware, hardware);
}
```